# (Should be) simple double validation

Tags: java, double

I'm having difficulty ensuring that doubles are validated correctly in my program. A user can enter an amount to deposit into the account, which should be a double (I know, it's not what I should be using, but it's part of the assignment guidelines). Theoretically, the user should be able to deposit any amount- not just £30, but say, £15.23.
This is the validation I currently have, which allows numbers, but prevents the entry of a full stop, which creates a number of problems.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static String getBalanceValidation()
{
    //Allow user input capabilities
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Declare variables needed for validation
    double dblInput = 0; //dblInput is set as 0
    String strNumber = ""; //strNumber is blank
    boolean bolSuccessful, bolNumeric;
    int intCount;
    char charLetter;


    do
    {
        //set bolSuccessful and bolNumeric as true
        bolSuccessful = true;
        bolNumeric = true;

        try //try user input
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the balance to be deposited: "); //User prompt
                strNumber = input.next(); //User input as string
                dblInput = Double.parseDouble(strNumber) ; //String input converted to double


            }// end of try

        catch (NumberFormatException e) //NumberFormatException disallows letters or symbols in value
            {
                System.out.println("Deposit value cannot contain letters!"); //Error message
                bolSuccessful = false; //set bolSuccessful as false

                continue; //Return to try
            }//end of number format catch


            //create for loop which checks each character throughout the string
            for (intCount = 0; intCount < strNumber.length(); intCount++)
                {
                    charLetter = strNumber.charAt(intCount); //charLetter is the alphanumeric value of a character in the string at the point dictated by intCount


                    if (!(charLetter >= '0') && (charLetter <= '9' ) //if charLetter is not between 0 and 9
                            || (charLetter == '.')) //or charLetter is not a full stop
                        {
                            bolNumeric = false; //Set bolNumeric as false
                        }//end of if construct
                }//end of for loop

            if (!bolNumeric) //if bolNumeric is false
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect input format! The balance must be numbers only!"); //Error message
                    bolSuccessful = false; //Set bolSuccessful as false
                }//end of if construct

    }while (!bolSuccessful); //While bolSuccessful is false, return to top


    return strNumber; //return strNumber to be used in main method
    //end of do method
}//end of getBalanceValidation method
```

I'm not sure whether it's because I've used NumberFormatException (is there something else for double?)

Many thanks

Comment: Define 'a number of problems'. Not sure whether *what* is because of ...? Not a real question.

Comment: I really hate comments that tell me that a variable is set to `true`: `//set bolSuccessful and bolNumeric as true`

Comment: I hate the comments too- but like I said, it's for an assignment. I was just told to comment like crazy.

Comment: Commenting like crazy can be fine but there's a difference between 'if bolNumeric is false' and 'if the input was not numeric'. The first is redundant, the latter explains what's happening.

Comment: what is the problem in short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **2 errors in your boolean expression** :

```
if (!(charLetter >= '0') && (charLetter <= '9' ) || (charLetter == '.'))
```

This condition is equivalent to :

```
if ((charLetter < '0') && (charLetter <= '9' ) || (charLetter == '.'))
```

Which can be simplified to :

```
if ((charLetter < '0') || (charLetter == '.'))
```

So the **`!` should be applied to the first two parts of the expression** :

```
if (!( (charLetter >= '0') && (charLetter <= '9') ) || (charLetter == '.'))
```

Moreover, since `.` is not a number, this expression is equivalent to :

```
if (!( (charLetter >= '0') && (charLetter <= '9') ))
```

**You probably meant `&&` not `||`** :

```
if (!( (charLetter >= '0') && (charLetter <= '9' ) ) && (charLetter != '.'))
```

Which means `if(not_a_number AND not_a_full-stop)`

Comment: Works a treat- Thank you very much. Should've known it wasn't or in this case, I was mainly working with validating names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `double number = input.nextDouble();` instead of `strNumber = input.next();`. This would allow you to input the `number` directly as `double` instead of `String`.

You would have to handle `InputMismatchException` in your catch block, and you are good to go. You won't need to validate to check the inclusion of `.`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier using a regex:

```
bolNumeric = strNumber.matches("[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?");
```

Explanation: The first number has to be within 1-9. Then as many as you want (including none) other numbers may follow. This is optionally followed by a dot, and then at least one, max 2 more digits.